# Why do arrays not count as a point when used as a return?

Tags: c, pointers, return, function-call

For the following C program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int64_t* newCopy(void* array, size_t newElements)
{
    int64_t newArray[newElements];

    for (size_t i = 0; i < newElements; i++) {
        newArray[i] = ((int64_t*)array)[i];     
    }
    int64_t* ptr = &newArray;

    return ptr;
}

int main() {
    int64_t array[3] = {1,2,3};
    int64_t* copy = newCopy(array,3);
    array[1] = 4;
    for (size_t i = 0; i<3;i++){
        printf("%ld\n",copy[i]);
    }
}
```

Returning newArray as itself for the function newCopy causes Segmentation Fault. Yet the function runs well if I create a new pointer variable ptr and assign the array into it.

As arrays are pointers then shouldn't returning it as it be okay?

Comment: Local variable lifetime is only within the function. Using a reference to such outside the function is Undefined Behaviour. So doesn't matter how you return it it is still wrong.

Comment: When the function `newCopy` returns, the life-time of all local variables ends, and they cease to exists. Any pointers you return to local variables will become immediately invalid. That includes arrays, and pointers to elements of those arrays.

Comment: Also note that `int64_t* ptr = &newArray;` is wrong in another way: The type of `&newArray` is `int64_t (*)[newElements]`. This is very different from `int64_t *`.

Comment: The difference is stack vs heap. After the function returns, the stack is lost, however you can allocate your memory (malloc) on the heap, it will be preserved, just don't forget to free it at some point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has nothing specific to do with array type.

The variable in discussion here, `newArray` is local to the scope of the function, and its lifetime is till the function execution scope. Once the function execution has finished and the control returns to the caller, all the memory locations allocated inside the function are invalid.

Attempt to use invalid memory will invoke [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), including but not limited to a segmentation fault.

As a solution, you can use allocator functions `malloc()` and family to allocate memory, captured in a pointer variable, and return that from the function, as the lifetime of the allocated memory is either until deallocation or the entire program lifetime, whichever is earlier.

Or you can also pass an array reference from the calling routine, so the function is not given the responsibility of acquiring the needed storage for something that goes further its control.  This allows you to decide how to allocate the new array.

```
/* if your array is going to operate on int64_t elements, better don't use void * as the type you pass in */
void newCopy(int64_t* array, int64_t *copy, size_t newElements)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < newElements; i++) {
        copy[i] = array[i];     
    }
}
```

(far simpler)

Comment: If possible, could you please show me how you would write the function?

Answer (score 0):

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int64_t* newCopy(void* array, size_t newElements)
{
    int64_t* newArray = calloc(newElements, sizeof(int64_t));
    
    for (size_t i = 0; i < newElements; i++) {
        newArray[i] = *(int64_t*)(array + i*8);     
    }
    
    return newArray;
}

int main() {
    int64_t array[3] = {1,2,3};
    int64_t* copy = newCopy(array,3);
    array[1] = 4;
    for (size_t i = 0; i<3;i++){
        printf("%ld\n",copy[i]);
    }
}
```

Found the answer ;-;

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).